# c# Is it possible to create a static object whilst at the same time, passsing it to a constructor or method of another object

Tags: c#, constructor, static

Something like this;

```
public static Group wsGroup = new Group(public static strVar wsStr = new strVar("Name", 10));
```

Basically what i'm trying to do is avoid . notation. I could of course define `wsStr` within `wsGroup` and reference it like `wsGroup.wsStr` but for reasons i can't get into here the customer only wants to reference `wsStr`. Now when they reference `wsGroup` it will take all the values within objects that have been passed to it's constructor and format them into one big string. I could of course do something like this;

```
public static strVar wsString = new strVar("Name", 10);
public static intVar wsValue = new intVar(10, "0000");

public static Group wsGroup = new Group(wsString, wsValue);
```

The problem with this is if i add an object in between `wsString` and `wsValue` and forget to add it to `wsGroup` then it will fail. So the idea of creating objects as they are passed to `wsGroup` makes for a fairly robust solution. Note these variables need to be visible to every method in the class. Note also that readability is very important here it cannot take more than a few lines to do this.

I am at the mercy of COBOL here. Trying to migrate COBOl code to C#. The objective is a %100 percent solution whilst the code is still readable for a COBOL programmer.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: So in order to solve the problem of not wanting to add `.` you want to make an even bigger problem which is less robust and a harder to maintain

Comment: As an aside, I expect you're not using names like these in your real code - I expect you're following regular .NET naming conventions. It's useful if you can do that in sample code in questions too, so that readers aren't distracted by the unconventional names. (If you *are* using unconventional names in your production code, I'd advise you to change that - but even if you don't do that, follow conventions in your questions, for the same reason.)

Comment: I should have mentioned this at the start. I am at the mercy of another language (COBOL). I am trying to create structures that COBOL people will see and understand and i am forced to migrate COBOL syntax. My primary goal is to make the application work 100% without manual changes whilst still being readable to a COBOL programmer

Comment: If that means there are additional constraints, those need to be in the question. Otherwise, you should expect the community to suggest idiomatic C# solutions. If the COBOL aspect doesn't actually impose extra constraints, but will just affect how you apply the solution, then it's worth writing the question as if COBOL weren't involved at all (i.e. in a conventional C# way).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would achieve this by avoiding using public fields at all. If you use properties, you can make them delegate to your group:

```
public class Container
{
     public static string DefaultName => DefaultGroup.Name;
     public static decimal DefaultPrice => DefaultGroup.Price;

     public static Group DefaultGroup { get; } = new Group("default name", 10m);
}
```

This illustrates the benefit of separating the *implementation* (fields) from the *API* (being able to write `Container.DefaultName`). It's almost never appropriate to make fields public. (There are exceptions to this, but they're few and far between. Natural constants - e.g. "the number of milliseconds in a second" - form one obvious exception, but you need to make sure they're *real* constants which can never change.)

Comment: That is beyond me. Do i still need to use dot notation to access the variables?

Comment: @blink: From where? With `Container`, you can just refer to `DefaultName`. No need for any dots. (I wanted to give a reasonably complete example, but you didn't give the name of the class that would have contained the static fields, so I made one up.)

Comment: Will that work if DefaultName is an object rather than a string?

Comment: @blink: Strings are objects. But yes, it would work with any type. If it's a mutable value type, you'd end up with a *copy* of the value from the group, but I'd argue that at that point you've got bigger problems anyway.

Comment: The new Group("default name", 10m) syntax, Is that adding the entry for DefaultName? Should there be a similar entry for DefaultPrice? How does it associate the group entries with the variables? I am obviously still missing something

Comment: @blink: The 10m is the value for DefaultPrice. The `DefaultName` property asks for the `Name` property from the `Group` referred to by `DefaultGroup`, and the `DefaultPrice` property asks for the `Price` property from that group. How comfortable are you with C# properties?

Comment: I think i'm beginning to understand. So Group would have properties like Name and Price. The constructor would initialize those values. The Container simply replaces the . notation with simplified names. Is that correct?

Comment: @blink: Yes. Within `Container`, writing `string x = DefaultName;` would be just like writing `string x = DefaultGroup.Name;`.